# Calling methods on objects in a ListView

Tags: android

I have a listview that is populated by a by objects from an "Offer" class I've written. Obviously, the `toString()` method is called and that's the text that's displayed in each list item. My question is, how do I implement an `onItemClickListener` that will call one of my getter or setter methods on the particular object whose toString method had been used to populate that item?

For example, I'd like to raise a toast or something when an item is clicked that retrieves a string my `getClaimCode()` method and displays in the toast (or whatever other dialog or even a new activity).

can I just call the methods by doing something like `item.getClaimCode()`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, but I do, and in onCreate() I call myListView.setOnItemClickListener(this).

Then for the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener interface, I have the method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Code
}
```

For you, you might do something like:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Arg2 is the position in the list so...
            OfferObject offer = (OfferObject) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            //Go to town...
}
```

Of course your Activity doesn't have to implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener and you could create the listener on the fly.

```
yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        OfferObject offer = (OfferObject) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        //Same idea here...
    }

});
```